# Python Failed to create a NewWriteableFile

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection

I had some github code to turn two .csv files into .records, to use for image recognition machine learning.

The github file is generate_tfrecord.py at https://github.com/datitran/raccoon_dataset/blob/master/generate_tfrecord.py, and I had to do some modifications to it, since apparently some of the code in it didn't exist in the libraries it uses.

For reference, the new code is:

```
"""
Usage:
  # From tensorflow/models/
  # Create train data:
  python generate_tfrecord.py --csv_input=data/train_labels.csv  --output_path=train.record

  # Create test data:
  python generate_tfrecord.py --csv_input=data/test_labels.csv  --output_path=test.record
"""
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function
from __future__ import absolute_import

import os
import io
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf

from PIL import Image
from object_detection.utils import dataset_util
from collections import namedtuple, OrderedDict

# tf.compat.v1.flags used to be tf.app.flags, but it apparently didn't exist, and like this it works better (aka. doesn't give that error)
flags = tf.compat.v1.flags
flags.DEFINE_string('csv_input', '', 'Path to the CSV input')
flags.DEFINE_string('output_path', '', 'Path to output TFRecord')
flags.DEFINE_string('image_dir', '', 'Path to images')
FLAGS = flags.FLAGS


# TO-DO replace this with label map
def class_text_to_int(row_label):
    if row_label == 'Car_8':
        return 1
    else:
        None


def split(df, group):
    data = namedtuple('data', ['filename', 'object'])
    gb = df.groupby(group)
    return [data(filename, gb.get_group(x)) for filename, x in zip(gb.groups.keys(), gb.groups)]


def create_tf_example(group, path):
    with tf.gfile.GFile(os.path.join(path, '{}'.format(group.filename)), 'rb') as fid:
        encoded_jpg = fid.read()
    encoded_jpg_io = io.BytesIO(encoded_jpg)
    image = Image.open(encoded_jpg_io)
    width, height = image.size

    filename = group.filename.encode('utf8')
    image_format = b'jpg'
    xmins = []
    xmaxs = []
    ymins = []
    ymaxs = []
    classes_text = []
    classes = []

    for index, row in group.object.iterrows():
        xmins.append(row['xmin'] / width)
        xmaxs.append(row['xmax'] / width)
        ymins.append(row['ymin'] / height)
        ymaxs.append(row['ymax'] / height)
        classes_text.append(row['class'].encode('utf8'))
        classes.append(class_text_to_int(row['class']))

    tf_example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
        'image/height': dataset_util.int64_feature(height),
        'image/width': dataset_util.int64_feature(width),
        'image/filename': dataset_util.bytes_feature(filename),
        'image/source_id': dataset_util.bytes_feature(filename),
        'image/encoded': dataset_util.bytes_feature(encoded_jpg),
        'image/format': dataset_util.bytes_feature(image_format),
        'image/object/bbox/xmin': dataset_util.float_list_feature(xmins),
        'image/object/bbox/xmax': dataset_util.float_list_feature(xmaxs),
        'image/object/bbox/ymin': dataset_util.float_list_feature(ymins),
        'image/object/bbox/ymax': dataset_util.float_list_feature(ymaxs),
        'image/object/class/text': dataset_util.bytes_list_feature(classes_text),
        'image/object/class/label': dataset_util.int64_list_feature(classes),
    }))
    return tf_example


def main(_):
    #io used to be python_io, but it apparently didn't exist, and like this it works better (aka. doesn't give that error)
    writer = tf.io.TFRecordWriter(FLAGS.output_path)
    path = os.path.join(FLAGS.image_dir)
    examples = pd.read_csv(FLAGS.csv_input)
    grouped = split(examples, 'filename')
    for group in grouped:
        tf_example = create_tf_example(group, path)
        writer.write(tf_example.SerializeToString())

    writer.close()
    output_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), FLAGS.output_path)
    print('Successfully created the TFRecords: {}'.format(output_path))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # tf.compat.v1.app.run() used to be tf.app.run(), but it apparently didn't exist, and like this it works better (aka. doesn't give that error)
    tf.compat.v1.app.run()
```

When ran, as specified in command prompt, using

```
generate_tfrecord.py --csv_input=images\test_labels.csv --image_dir=images\test --output_path=test.record
```

and

```
generate_tfrecord.py --csv_input=images\train_labels.csv --image_dir=images\train --output_path=train.record
```

respectively, I get the following error:

```
C:\My_Path>generate_tfrecord.py --csv_input=images\train_labels.csv --image_dir=images\train --output_path=train.record
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\My_Path\generate_tfrecord.py", line 103, in <module>
    tf.compat.v1.app.run()
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\platform\app.py", line 40, in run
    _run(main=main, argv=argv, flags_parser=_parse_flags_tolerate_undef)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 299, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 250, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "C:\My_Path\generate_tfrecord.py", line 88, in main
    writer = tf.io.TFRecordWriter(FLAGS.output_path)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\lib\io\tf_record.py", line 218, in __init__
    compat.as_bytes(path), options._as_record_writer_options(), status)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\errors_impl.py", line 556, in __exit__
    c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: Failed to create a NewWriteableFile:  : The system cannot find the path specified.
; No such process
```

How do I fix the

> tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: Failed to create a NewWriteableFile:  : The system cannot find the path specified. ; No such process

error?

For further reference, someone had an almost identical problem at

[tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: Failed to create a NewWriteableFile:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49210844/tensorflow-python-framework-errors-impl-notfounderror-failed-to-create-a-newwri)

And the offered answer was

> flags.DEFINE_string('csv_input', '', 'Path to the CSV input') flags.DEFINE_string('output_path', '', 'Path to output TFRecord')
>   Replace the 'Path to the CSV input' and 'Path to output TFRecord' with actual path.

Starting from MyPath, which is where I run generate_tfrecord.py from, the csv files which I use (test_labels.csv and train_labels.csv respectively) are inside a folder named "images", and there are two folders which images named "train" and "test" inside it, along with the csv files".

I've tried several variations of changing the paths as advised such as:

```
'''
flags.DEFINE_string('csv_input', '', 'Path to the CSV input')
flags.DEFINE_string('output_path', '', 'Path to output TFRecord')
flags.DEFINE_string('image_dir', '', 'Path to images')
'''
flags.DEFINE_string('csv_input', '', '/images/train_labels.csv')
flags.DEFINE_string('output_path', '', '/images/train.record')
flags.DEFINE_string('image_dir', '', '/images/train')
```

But they were ineffective. I've tried front slashes, back slashes, without quotes, with "" quotes, nothing worked. I've also searched how to declare a path in flags, didn't help.

What should I do to fix the program and get the .record files?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing it to:

```
flags.DEFINE_string('csv_input', 'C:\\yourfolder\\train_labels.csv', 'Path to the CSV input')
flags.DEFINE_string('output_path', 'C:\\yourfolder\\train.record', 'Path to output TFRecord')
flags.DEFINE_string('image_dir', 'C:\\yourfolder\\images\\train', 'Path to images')
```